# How can I get back the gizmo

Tags: 3d-view, interface, gizmo

I moved the eyes and the eye bones on an existing (purchased) Rigify rig. The rig still works and I can move the controls by selecting and hitting G or R. But the gizmo no longer shows up. I re-parented and applied the armature modifiers and re-added them. Nothing changed.

Here are 2 screen shots to illustrate:

[image: missing tool]

[image: tool not missing]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thx, M

Comment: Don't understand the question! What do you mean by "active tool"? - Your annotation is just pointing at one of the lower lip controls and the head tilt control which are the same in both images as far as I can see. The only difference between the two is that the N panel is open on the first image. Hit 'N' and then the Tool tab in the sidebar to show it in the second image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This widget that allows you to interact with an active tool is called a gizmo.

It is still present in your second screenshot, but your *"Transform Point Pivot"* (the point from which the transforms happen) is set to *"3D Cursor"*, which is somewhere in your scene outside your current viewpoint:

[image]

Set it back to *"Median Point"* like it is in your first screenshot and it should show up in the same place.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply/answer!  I was surprised that I could move the eyes/eye bones without breaking the rig so I assumed I had broken it somehow. So happy I didn't break it.